# Can we create lookup field to territory on Account or custom objects?

Tags: territory-management, territory

I am trying to create a lookup to Territory on the Account object. But while creating a lookup field, I am not able to see the Territory object in "Related To" dropdown box(screenshot given below). I am not able to see this on custom objects also.

Am I missing something here or Salesforce not allows us to add Territory as lookup to other objects?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Accounts are related to Territories via a junction object [ObjectTerritory2Association](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_objectterritory2association.htm?q=objectterritory2association) - that is, one Account can be associated to more than one Territory rather than trying to construct a lookup relationship (which is why the option does not exist)

Your app should be querying this junction record to find all associated territories

[Schema](https://architect.salesforce.com/diagrams/template-gallery/sales-cloud-territory-management-data-model)

[image]